what php regex expression would do it for a preg_match_all to get desired strings out of a html string
i am struggling since days (my regex know-how is very much lacking...) to grab strings from an html string...
i have a html string with repeating html like this:
`<tr class="hintergrundfarbe2">
<td><a href="/w/index.php?title=Zunlon&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Zunlon (Seite nicht vorhanden)">Zunlon</a>, <a href="/wiki/Chinesische_Schrift" title="Chinesische Schrift">chinesisch</a>&#160;<link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r184932629"><span lang="zh-Hans" class="Hans">尊隆</span>
</td>`

my php coding reads like this:
    $goForIt = "/" . $search_term . "/i";
    // narrow down the hits from scraped table
    preg_match_all($goForIt, $htmlScrapedTable, $match);

this is what i get as an result:
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Zunl"
    1 => "Zunl"
    2 => "Zunl"
  ]
]

the returned array is matching the input §search_term BUT ... i need to have the full string, in this example "Zunlon" returned!
is there any chance to make it happen through a regex expression or do i need to loop over the html string?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/14853083
